# I want to save the data type float in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, database, save

Im trying to save the decimal number to float type.
the dicimal number is rated by star-rating-svg.js gem. and i got currentRating.
When i click star-rating, i can show the rating on input number field like 3.5.
After i put another data(title, desc) and submit button. but it can't saved like 3.5 but just 3.0...
Thnks your help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJClj.png)

im my _form.html.erb

```
<div class="col-11">
          <%= render 'score'%>
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
               <input class="mt-3" type="number" id="rating" name="rating" 
                            step="0.5" min="0.0" max="5.0" precision="2" />
          </div>
      </div>
```

in my _score.html.erb

```
<div class="my-rating jq-star" style="text-align:center;"></div>
    <script>
$(function() {
  $(".my-rating").starRating({
    ...
    callback: function(currentRating, $el){
        parseFloat(currentRating);
        document.getElementById("rating").value = currentRating;
        console.log(currentRating);
    ...
```

my ca_reviews_controller.rb

```
def create 
@ca_review = CaReview.new(title: params[:title], review: params[:review], care_article_id: params[:care_article_id], user_id: current_user.id, rating: params[:rating])
```

and my schema file..

```
create_table "ca_reviews", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "review"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.float "rating"
```

<< i changed rating data-option decimal to float cause it had same problem. it saved 3.5 to 0.3e1 not 0.35e1.

Comment: `parseFloat()` does not mutate the input, it returns the Number type that the string was converted into. Besides that, that will have no effect anyway since you directly use it as a string anyway.

Comment: @Randy Casburn THanks. Then, what should i do if i want to save the number x point 5 (e.g. 1.5 / 2.5 / 3.5 / 4.5) correctly?

Comment: if `currentRating` is (presumably) a string containing that Number (1.5, 2.5, etc), you don't need to parse it - use it directly as the input element's `value`. All input values are strings.

Comment: Your intent is to parse the string ("1.5", "2.5", etc) into a float on the _server_. HTTP/AJAX will always transfer the values from the browser to the server as string types.

Comment: Could you change t.float to t.decimal and use the number_with_precision helper? There is more info in the heper [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_with_precision)